# Create adjacency matrix from list of lists depending on coorccurences of elements

Tags: list, adjacency-matrix

I have a list of lists such as: MyList = [['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['A', 'C']].

I want to create a symmetric matrix where such that its (i, j)-th element be the number of times when the "i" and "j" elements co-occur in any sub-list in "MyList". For example, 'A' and 'B' co-occur in two lists (1st and 2nd) in "MyList". So, it would mean that MyAdj['A', 'B'] = MyAdj['B', 'A'] = 2. Any help or redirection to a similar question would be highly appreciated!

Here, "i" and "j" need not be the elements ("A" or "B") but just unique numeric numbers (0 and 1, for example) relating to each element in the entire collection of lists in "MyList". So, for the "MyList" example above, it would mean MyAdj will be a 4x4 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have to first find how many unique elements you are searching and sort them (this will be your matrix shape). Then for each i, j check how many times they occur simultaneously on each list of MyList. Below is and example in python3:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['A', 'C']]
unique_elem = sorted(set(sum(my_list, []))) # sorted list of unique elements
n = len(unique_elem)
my_adj = np.zeros((n,n), dtype= int) # matrix (n,n)

for i, a in enumerate(unique_elem):
    for j, b in enumerate(unique_elem):
        my_adj[i][j] = sum([True for seq in my_list if a in seq and b in seq])
```

where my_adj outputs:

```
   A B C D
A[[3 2 2 1]
B [2 2 1 1]
C [2 1 3 1]
D [1 1 1 2]]
```